# How can I sum the sums of a recordset based on the value of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my T-SQL Code:

```
SELECT  H.ORDER_DATE 'Order Date',
        SUM(D.WORK_QTY) 'Work Qty',
        SUM(TD. TRAN_QTY) 'Transaction Qty',
        IM.PUMJ_CD

FROM [dbo].[ORDER_HEADER] H

    LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAIL D ON D.ORDER_ID = H.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_HEADER T ON T.ORDER_ID = H.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_DETAIL TD ON TD.TRAN_ID = T.TRAN_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_TYPE TT ON TT.TRAN_TYPE_ID = TD.TRAN_TYPE_ID 
    LEFT JOIN ITM_MST IM ON IM.ITM_NM = D.ITEM_NAME

WHERE   TD.TRAN_TYPE_ID = '231' 
        AND PUMJ_CD IN ('BF','BR','SHFT','BJ','TJ')
        AND H.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '20170403' AND '20170407'

GROUP BY    IM.PUMJ_CD,
            H.ORDER_DATE

ORDER BY    H.ORDER_DATE
```

and it returns the recordset:

```
Order Date | Work Qty | Transaction Qty | PUMJ_CD
-------------------------------------------------
20170403   | 10       | 7               | BF
20170403   | 24       | 12              | BR
20170403   | 16       | 14              | TJ
20170404   | 15       | 10              | BF
```

Is it possible to sum the rows from the record set where:
 'Order Date' is the same,and 
 PUMJ_CD IN ('BF','BR')
and have the resulting record set look like:

```
Order Date | Work Qty | Transaction Qty | PUMJ_CD
-------------------------------------------------
20170403   | 34       | 19              | TOTAL
20170403   | 16       | 14              | TJ
20170404   | 15       | 10              | BF
```

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this in one query, but with my limited knowledge I haven't been successful. I've tried looking online, but I'm finding it difficult to describe what I need with a question in google. If anyone could help out or point me in the right direction it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Union over two data sets.

1 - without BR and BF 
2 - just BR and BF as Total

```
SELECT  H.ORDER_DATE 'Order Date',
        SUM(D.WORK_QTY) 'Work Qty',
        SUM(TD. TRAN_QTY) 'Transaction Qty',
        IM.PUMJ_CD

FROM [dbo].[ORDER_HEADER] H

    LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAIL D ON D.ORDER_ID = H.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_HEADER T ON T.ORDER_ID = H.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_DETAIL TD ON TD.TRAN_ID = T.TRAN_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_TYPE TT ON TT.TRAN_TYPE_ID = TD.TRAN_TYPE_ID 
    LEFT JOIN ITM_MST IM ON IM.ITM_NM = D.ITEM_NAME

WHERE   TD.TRAN_TYPE_ID = '231' 
        AND PUMJ_CD IN  ('SHFT','BJ','TJ')  -- NO BR BF
        AND H.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '20170403' AND '20170407'

GROUP BY    IM.PUMJ_CD,
            H.ORDER_DATE

union

SELECT  H.ORDER_DATE,
        SUM(D.WORK_QTY),
        SUM(TD. TRAN_QTY),
        'TOTAL'

FROM [dbo].[ORDER_HEADER] H

    LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAIL D ON D.ORDER_ID = H.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_HEADER T ON T.ORDER_ID = H.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_DETAIL TD ON TD.TRAN_ID = T.TRAN_ID
    LEFT JOIN TRAN_TYPE TT ON TT.TRAN_TYPE_ID = TD.TRAN_TYPE_ID 
    LEFT JOIN ITM_MST IM ON IM.ITM_NM = D.ITEM_NAME

WHERE   TD.TRAN_TYPE_ID = '231' 
        AND PUMJ_CD IN ('BF','BR')  -- ONLY BF AND BR AS TOTAL
        AND H.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '20170403' AND '20170407'

GROUP BY   H.ORDER_DATE
```

Comment: This worked! I just had to replace the period mistype in the 2nd SELECT statement and the query executed successfully. I also added an 
    ORDER BY H.ORDER_DATE
to get the rows in order. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use `CASE` for the aggregation and in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT  H.ORDER_DATE as [Order Date],
        SUM(D.WORK_QTY) as [Work Qty],
        SUM(TD. TRAN_QTY) as [Transaction Qty],
        (CASE WHEN IM.PUMJ_CD IN ('BF','BR') THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE IM.PUMJ_CD
         END) as PUMJ_CD
FROM . . .
GROUP BY H.ORDER_DATE,
         (CASE WHEN IM.PUMJ_CD IN ('BF','BR') THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE IM.PUMJ_CD
          END)
```

This is a little different from what you want.  It will always return `TOTAL` for those two values.

You can do a slight modification if you want an individual value:

```
SELECT  H.ORDER_DATE as [Order Date],
        SUM(D.WORK_QTY) as [Work Qty],
        SUM(TD. TRAN_QTY) as [Transaction Qty],
        (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MIN(IM.PUMJ_CD)
              ELSE (CASE WHEN IM.PUMJ_CD IN ('BF','BR') THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE IM.PUMJ_CD)
         END) as PUMJ_CD
FROM . . .
GROUP BY H.ORDER_DATE,
         (CASE WHEN IM.PUMJ_CD IN ('BF','BR') THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE IM.PUMJ_CD
          END)
```

Comment: Gordon, first of all, thank you for the help.
I've tried your solution, and both only change the PUMJ_CD values of the 'BF' and 'BR' rows to 'TOTAL', it does not sum the rows like I wanted to. Also, the GROUP BY does not execute successfully with the CASE statement, I had to replace it with just the IM.PUMJ_CD. I'm not sure if that is why the rows did not sum, perhaps you can shed some light on that?

Comment: @J.Lee . . . The first version should execute fine with the `CASE`.  You have to be sure that the `CASE` is the same in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.